# Minimum number of capacitors

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, dielectric

I require a capacitance of 2×10^-6 F in a circuit across a potential difference of 1kV . I have a large number of 1×10^-6 F is available which can each withstand a potential of 400V. Suggest a possible arrangement that requires minimum number of capacitors.

I believe that since in series connection the potential difference is constant we'd have to consider parallel but then the net potential difference decreases and will increase the number of capacitors. But the question is minimum amount of capacitors so im kinda stuck there.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  You will have to show your working so far and thoughts on the matter.  i.e. where you are stuck or why you have the right answer etc.

Comment: I believe that since in series connection the potential difference is constant we'd have to consider parallel but then the net potential difference decreases and will increase the number of capacitors. But the question is minimum amount of capacitors so im kinda stuck there.

Comment: hint: with two caps in series max voltage doubles, while with two caps in parallel max voltage stays the same.

Comment: Is the answer 8 capacitors, 4 in parallel series to another 4 in parallel? Then the net capacitance would be 2 ..but what about voltage how do I solve that?

Comment: And don't forget balancing resistors...

Comment: @MattYoung, but there are no resistors in this problem *confused*.

Comment: @user3832498, that can't be the solution because you essentially have 4uF cap in series with another 4uF cap but both only have 400V ratings where the problem statement asks for 1kV.

Comment: @MattYoung, the balancing resistors would be to ensure uniform voltage across the capacitors (similar to resistors for parallel diodes to ensure equal current division)? If not, what exactly is their purpose?

Comment: For equal-sized capacitors in series (with balancing resistors), the voltage distributes evenly across the individual capacitors. Two 400V capacitors in series can withstand 800V, three can withstand 1200V, etc. The balancing resistors should be sized so that the current through them is at least 10x the maximum leakage current through the capacitors, and you need to make sure that the resulting RC time constant is still adequate for the application.

Comment: If you _think_ you have an answer, then it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.  In fact it is encouraged.  And what is even nicer, there are schematic tools available to be clearer.

Comment: @DaveTweed, As in something like [this?](http://cdn.instructables.com/F10/R93J/H347FJTY/F10R93JH347FJTY.LARGE.jpg). Also, why 10x leakage?

Comment: @sherrellbc: No, not like that. The resistors need to have equal values if the capacitances are equal -- or more generally, values that are proportional to the inverses of the capacitances. 10x leakage is just a rule of thumb; it keeps the actual voltages within 10% of the nominal values despite variations in the actual capacitor leakage currents.

Comment: This is the kind of a homework question that leaves people with all the wrong impressions. Leakage currents? What leakage currents? A shorted capacitor? Nah. Never happens. And so on...

Comment: @KubaOber, i still have no idea how to solve this :/

Comment: We do engineering here.  Instead of the cumbersome "10^-6", we say "micro".  That can be abbreviated with a lower case mu, or just "u" if you can't do a mu.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is fairly old, I'll just post the answer just for the kick of it :)

Connect a branch of 4 caps in series which makes a .... 0.25e-6F (250nF) at 1600V.
Now create another 7 such branches (a total of 8) and connect them all in parallel.

You'll end up having 8 branches of 250nF each all capable of 1600V connected in parallel.

That makes ... 8 * 250nF = 2uF @ 1600V. Tadaaa!!

Comment: You will also want to add high-value resistors across each capacitor to keep the voltage across each cap the same.  Otherwise, it is possible that the voltage across some caps is higher than others.

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be 42 ?

Or is it more likely to be 42 * 6 / 14 ?

Comment: "What do you get when you multiply six by nine?"

Comment: ^ I got this one: 54. Glad to be here.

Comment: Can you explain this answer?

Comment: First off from the "Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy" the answer to everything is 42. Then I pondered a while and realized that 42 may very well part of the calculation to the answer to the question. Nothing to do about capacitors - just a funny number.